# Triggerig Jenkins pipeline job after code pushed to github

Tags: jenkins, github

I want to know how we can setup a jenkins pipeline job which gets triggered after each commit made github private repository.

I am able to do it using a freestyle job but not able to do it using a pipeline.

I did setup the gihub project url, GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling and wrote a simple pipeline script of checking out the branch.

When I do a changes in the branch and commit it the build wont get triggered.

Can I get a solution on this please?

Comment: Is your pipeline job in Jenkins disabled by any chance ?

Comment: No I can trigger it manually...

Comment: Check Jenkins logs to see if webhook is hitting Jenkins ? Do you see GitHub webhook trigger status code as 200 in GitHub ?

Answer (score 0):

It works when we add a timestamp block in the pipeline code.

Answer (score 0):

I m able to trigger the pipeline by Adding a GitHub Webhook in Jenkins Pipeline.
I have followed steps mentioned in this [blog](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline).

In my case jenkins is running on `localhost`. Replacing `localhost` with your `jenkins_url` should work.

Also, I did not found **GitHub Pull Requests** mentioned in the blog, so I skipped that step.

After completing the configuration you have to build the pipeline manually once, after that everytime a developer commits a code to GitHub, pipeline build will be triggered.